# Modal page shows page shadow on physical device, none on emulator

Tags: javascript, ios, css, user-interface, nativescript

I'm currently creating a simple subsription page for an app developed using Nativescript. It's presented as a modal page with a little bit of styling and all the usual jazz to make it look nice and neat. To make sure that it looks somewhat like a pop-up dialog i've removed the background as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4300) on github and set the Page background to *transparent*. This works perfectly fine on an emulator but when I launch it on a physical device it leaves a shadow. It's barely visible but it is still too much to make us ship it.

**Emulator without a shadow**
[image]

**Physical device with shadow**
[image]

This issue is only present on a physical iPad which is a 9.7' 2018 model with OS 13.1.2.
The code from the parentView is as follows,

```
exports.onUpdateSubscriptionTap = async() => {
  const option = {
    context: { viewModel: settingsViewModel },
    closeCallback: () => {
      license = settingsViewModel.license;
      onUpdate();
    },
    fullscreen: false
  };
  page.showModal('~/views/settings/fmprompt-page', option);
};
```

And the XML building the dialog is as follows,

```
<Page borderRadius="40" backgroundColor="transparent" loaded="onLoaded" shownModally="onShownModally" showingModally="onShowingModally" 
  xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" automationText="FMPrompt" >
<StackLayout class="layout" height="50%" verticalAlignment="top">
    <Label class="prompt-title" text="{{ L('settings.subscription_dialog_title') }}" textWrap="true" automationText="prompt-title"/>
    <Label class="prompt-detail" text="{{ L('settings.subscription_dialog_msg') }}" textWrap="true" automationText="prompt-details"/>

    <GridLayout columns="auto,auto,auto,auto,auto" horizontalAlignment="center" height="50">
      <TextField id="inputField1" col="0" class="prompt-field" hint="ABC" automationText="prompt-field" 
                textChange="onTextChangeOne" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="allcharacters" maxLength="3" />
      <Label text="-" col="1" />
      <TextField id="inputField2" col="2" class="prompt-field" hint="DEF" automationText="prompt-field" 
                textChange="onTextChangeTwo" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="allcharacters" maxLength="3" />
      <Label text="-" col="3"/>
      <TextField id="inputField3" col="4" class="prompt-field" hint="GHE" automationText="prompt-field" 
                textChange="onTextChangeThree" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="allcharacters" maxLength="3" />
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout columns="auto,auto" horizontalAlignment="center">
        <Button class="prompt-btn" text="{{ L('cancel') }}" tap="onCancelTap" col="0" />
        <Button class="prompt-btn" text="{{ L('OK') }}" tap="onOKTap" col="1"/>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
</Page>
```

If anyone can spot where I go wrong or what's causing this weird shadow to appear, and solution or a tip would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
So i've tried a few different iOS runtimes on my iPad and Simulator. This shadow presents itself on all runtimes tested (10.3, 13.1, 13.3) but not on the 13.0 runtime which i find odd.

It is some time ago since i last did native iOS development but I thought i could recall a time where modal ViewControllers didn't show any shadow as in the first picture. Is this a new design choice from Apple? I did the following test by writing a super simple native iOS app and the shadow still presents its ugly face.

[image]

Can this "shadow" be removed and how?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you mean the shadow appears only on iOS 9 but not in latest versions?

Comment: It's iOS v. 13.1.2 that i'm running. It's the 9.7 inch model from 2018.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to make sure again - the issue exists only on iOS 13.x?

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. It turns out, this shadow presents itself on ios version 10.3, 13.3 and 13.1 on both a physical device and simulators. The only known version of iOS on which this shadow doesn't present itself is v. 13.0 on emulator (still haven't gotten around to downgrade my ipad)